# Why methods in DynamicObject class are not generic?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, dynamic

I was reading [this](http://blog.colinmackay.net/archive/2009/06/04/Dynamic-Objects-in-C-4.0.aspx) article about **Dynamic Objects in C# 4.0**.
In that example second argument of function TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result) is of type Object. I looked in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx) and noticed that other methods are getting arguments as Object as well. Why does these functions not generic?
From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)

> In relation to simple assignments, boxing and unboxing are
>   computationally expensive processes

If boxing/unboxing are expensive wouldn't it be better to use generics?

Thanks.

Comment: How often do you think the caller of `TryGetMember` actually knows what type they're going to get?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note the "in relation to simple assignments". In other words, compared with one of the cheapest possible operations, boxing is expensive.

Compared with the rest of the machinery involved in dynamic typing, boxing is cheap :)

If `TryGetMember` were generic, that would mean the *caller* would have to know what type to expect. One of the points of dynamic typing is that the caller *can't* guarantee what's going to happen. If I write:

```
dynamic foo = GetDynamicValueFromSomewhere();
Console.WriteLine(foo.SomeProperty);
```

that's only going to resolve which overload of `Console.WriteLine` to use *after* `SomeProperty` has been evaluated. It doesn't have an "expected" return type... so what generic type argument would you expect to use?

Bear in mind that most dynamic typing scenarios will use `object` as the intermediate expression type in the CLR anyway. If I write:

```
dynamic x = 10;
```

that's *already* boxing. You can't represent "an unboxed value type of an indeterminate type" in the CLR. (How much space would it allocate?)

Comment: @OP: Not only that the caller can't guarantee the type, the purpose of the dynamic typing is that the caller does not **care** what is the returning type, as long as it has a `SomeProperty` property. It's nowhere specified that the type must be a value or a ref type, so the existence of boxing operation will be unknown until runtime.

Comment: Even so, the performance penalty of boxing isn't actually the allocation, it's the side effects of doing an allocation. Call this is a tight loop and your gen-0 collection frequency goes up, which could cause more promotions to gen-1, which in turn could increase the likelyhood of a gen-2 collection. I would be much happier if the API had some sort of value-type struct returned with a superset of the types. Like an old VARIANT but not a union.